# What is the best way to run a python process on a separate compute instance with Google Cloud Composer?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I would like to be able to spin up a compute instance (not already created), install dependencies, run python process, tear down instance in one airflow dag.

I have come across two options:

- [Kubernetes-pod-operator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator)
- A hacky way to do it [here](https://medium.com/snipfeed/practical-guide-how-to-scale-up-your-work-flow-with-airflow-and-cloud-composer-3d30ea9f7c42) (this requires having code sitting in storage which is not ideal)

Are there any other ways or operators that would make this easy?

Comment: By "compute instance", do you mean Compute Engine instance? If you just want to run a simple job as you stated (Python process), just package it in a container, use the KubernetesPodOperator as you suggested and run the job in the Kubernetes cluster created by Google Cloud Composer (do a separate pool for your job though). It's the simplest solution.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to have a task in your DAG that creates a VM instance with specific dependencies, runs a python process and delete/stop the VM afterwards.
I believe this can be done with the [bashoperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/bash.html), the [GceInstanceTemplateCopyOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/gcp/compute.html#gceinstancetemplatecopyoperator), the [Cloud build operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/gcp/cloud_build.html)